# How to connect two routers but only one Wifi signal with Ethernet cable? possible?

Tags: wireless-networking

Take a look at my connection in the attached image.

The yellow line is dividing first with second floor.
Is it possible to have one signal with both router? 
Linksys is giving me ~25mbps while Netgear ~75mbps in the second floor.
Linksys is giving me ~35mbps while Netgear ~15mbps in the first floor.

But i have to be changing to Linksys when i go to the first floor, is it posible to merge both signal to have a strong one?and if it is, how?

I know i can extend the signal from the main router (Linksys) but since it is weaker than Netgear i prefer no to.
I just want to move around the house without changing AP in my phone or laptop

[image]

Comment: You could get a repeater for one floor, then you would have just one signal.

Comment: Turn off DHCP on the second floor router, and turn off wireless in whichever one you want.

Comment: I dont think it is possible since i want to merge both signal, like thicking my phone. If i'm connected to Linksys in the first floor and move to the second i want the phone to change AP automaticly to Netgear without losing connection to Linksys... no just keep one like you suggested. but receive both at the same time.